# NUnitLite on MonoTouch: tests succeed but don't get marked as executed in the UI

Tags: xamarin.ios, nunit, touch.unit

I'm on MonoTouch 6.0.4 and have implemented a Unit test using MonoTouch's NUnitLite.
If I execute a test and end it with an `Assert()` I can see from the logs that the test executed successfully:

> Tests run: 1 Passed: 0 Inconclusive: 0 Failed: 1 Ignored: 0

But in the UI, the test result is not reflected:[image: Test Result]

The test method:

```
[Test]
public void TestPing()
{
    APIPingResult oRes = oManager.PingConnector.Ping(5);
    Assert.True(oRes.Success);
}
```

Just a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *known* (I've noticed it before) bug.

The status is updated correctly when running all the tests, e.g. **Run Everything**, or all the test in a specific suite, e.g. **Run all**.

However when running a specific test the update is now done (actually I think it's just not refreshed). Note that the test result is still sent to the writer's output (e.g. Application Output or on the device console).

**Update:** Fixed in GIT (both 0.7 and master branches).

Comment: I can see the output, yes. But my testers don't :-) It used to work in previous versions even when running single tests. Will it get fixed by any chance?

Comment: @Krumelur Good point (testers) and yes it worked with NUnitLite 0.6. Since 5.4 we're now shipping 0.7 (*master* has 0.8 and the same issue). It never was a high priority (and it took me a while to notice it) but, as you just gave a very good reason, I'll look into it.